# How can I call method from one form on another

Tags: c#, winforms

I have this method that is in my "Parent" form:

```
        public void menjanjeMenia(Form meni){
            if (aktivnaForma != null){
                aktivnaForma.Close();
            }
            aktivnaForma = meni;
            meni.TopLevel = false;
            meni.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            meni.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
            this.panelMeni.Controls.Add(meni);
            meni.BringToFront();
            meni.Show();
            glavnaL.Text = meni.Text;
        }
```

How can I call this method from my other form("Parent" form never closes).
I tried to make new instance of "Parent" form but it doesn't work. No error just closes the form.

Comment: Why are you saying 'it doesn't work' ; what are your expected results? Which form closes, in your code I see at least 3 of them

Comment: you can use singleton, and access the instance using static method. Or you can make static method